# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error in Java 10

Tags: java, mysql

Recently I wrote this code for connecting to MySQL in Eclipse, I am using Java 10 but I run this code I found. I add a sql.connector.jar file also into my class path but still same error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Code:

```
package ExamplePackage;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


public class ConnectionManager {

static Connection con;
static String url;

public static Connection getConnection()
{

   try
   {
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema.student"; 
      // assuming "DataSource" is your DataSource name
     //String connectionUrl  = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-05S6KIJ;databaseName=users;";

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      try
      {             
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"Shaik","Shaik@786"); 

      // assuming your SQL Server's username is "username"               
      // and password is "password"

      }

      catch (SQLException ex)
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println(e);
   }

return con;
   }
   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't even need to call `Class.forName` in Java 10.  I'll bet the connector JAR is not on the classpath.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you check the version of the driver that you have loaded on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not in your project code, you need to add the **com.mysql.jdb*.jar** driver in your project. 
The *Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");* is trying to load the driver that is not found -> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver .